# Scala how to convert Array[Map[String,String]] to Map[String, Map[String,String]]

Tags: arrays, string, scala

I have string of columns and they are grouped by they purpose etc address cols and personal info cols.
`val columns="address:addressLine,address:city,address:state,address:zipCode,person:firstName,person:lastName,person:middleName"`

I wanted them to be arranged like that:

`lastName->person,zipCode->address`

So every pair like `lastName->person` would be a Map. I wanted these Maps to be placed inside another Map, like that:

```
columnSchema -> {
lastName->person,
zipCode->address
}
```

So it would be Map[String,Map[String,String]]

I started by doing it like that:

```
columns.split(",").map(_.split(":")).map(x=>Map(x(1)->x(0)))
```

What I got is:

```
Array[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]] = Array(Map(addressLine -> address), Map(city -> address), Map(state -> address), Map(zipCode -> address), Map(firstName -> person), Map(lastName -> person), Map(middleName -> person))
```

So I got an Array[Map[String,String]].
How could I make it a Map[String,Map[String,String]]?
I tried to do it like:

```
Map("columnSchema" -> columns.split(",").map(_.split(":")).map(x=>Map(x(1)->x(0))))
```

However it still returns an array of Maps:

```
scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Array[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]]]
```

How to get rid of an Array?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Similar to what you have except add in `toMap` to convert the `Array` of tuples to a `Map`

`Map("columnSchema" -> columns.split(",").map(_.split(":")).map(as => as(1) -> as(0)).toMap)`

Returns:

```
Map[String, Map[String, String]] = 
Map(columnSchema -> 
  HashMap(city -> address,
          middleName -> person,
          state -> address,
          addressLine -> address,
          zipCode -> address,
          lastName -> person,
          firstName -> person)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option could be splitting on `:` or `,` using a character class `[,:]` and  then group the result in collections of 2 and map using a partial function.

```
val res: Map[String, Map[String, String]] = Map(
  "columnSchema" -> 
    columns.split("[,:]").grouped(2)
    .map { case Array(k, v) => v -> k }.toMap
)
```

Output

```
Map(
columnSchema -> Map(
    city -> address,
    middleName -> person,
    state -> address,
    addressLine -> address,
    zipCode -> address,
    lastName -> person,
    firstName -> person
    )
)
```